# Small perturbation of $A$ in normal equation

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I'm studying the least squares problem. My professor told in class that small perturbation in $A$ does not mean small perturbation in $A^TA$, and so the relative perturbation of $x$ will depend on $\kappa^2(A),$ where $\kappa(A)$ is the condition number of $A$. I want to get an estimation of $\frac{\|\Delta x\|}{\|x\|},$ when we perturb $A$, but got stuck. Here's my attempt so far:
$$A^TAx = A^Tb.$$ Perturbing $A$ gives us
$(A-\Delta A)^T(A-\Delta A)(x-\Delta x) = (A-\Delta A)^Tb.$ This implies
$$ (A^T-(\Delta A)^T)(A-\Delta A)(x - \Delta x) = A^Tb-(\Delta A)^Tb \iff \\
(A^TA - A^T\Delta A - (\Delta A)^TA - (\Delta A)^T(\Delta A))x - (A^TA - A^T\Delta A - (\Delta A)^TA - (\Delta A)^T(\Delta A))(\Delta x) = A^Tb-(\Delta A)^Tb \iff \\
(- A^T\Delta A - (\Delta A)^TA - (\Delta A)^T(\Delta A))x - (A^TA - A^T\Delta A - (\Delta A)^TA - (\Delta A)^T(\Delta A))(\Delta x) = -(\Delta A)^Tb\\
$$

How should I proceed?